# simplemembership MVC4 get username by userId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, membership, simplemembership

Someone who works with MVC4 and the SIMPLEMEMBERSHIP knows how can I get a username by the userId? The user is not logged in and I want to delete it, and to delete I have to use

```
Membership.DeleteUser(string username)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `GetUserNameFromId` method of the `SimpleMembershipProvider` as such:

```
SimpleMembershipProvider provider = new SimpleMembershipProvider();
string name = provider.GetUserNameFromId(id);
```

Ensure you have a reference to `WebMatrix.WebData` so you can use the `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

Comment: This does not work for me. Is there another way? I get the following error: "You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site." But strangely, I already have the call in my _AppStart.cshtml because I've gotten this error before. If I try to make the call again it tells me you can't call it more than once...

Comment: If you ask this as a separate question and post a link to the question here, I will be able to provide a fuller answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleMembershipProvider provider = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

string username= provider.GetUserNameFromId(12345); 

//12345 is the id in SM UserProfile db table
```