# Get UserName by UserId and display in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 application how would I go about getting a `Username` from a given `UserId` and display it in a `View`?

Note - I do not need the `Username` of the *current* `User`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192660/simplemembership-mvc4-get-username-by-userid

Comment: You've tagged your question with MVC4 and SimpleMembership, but neither uses OWIN. OWIN is used by ASP.NET Identity in conjunction with MVC5. Please confirm what you're actually using. Regardless, you shouldn't try to do this with either one in your view. That's not the place for logic like this.

Comment: yes, sorry. I using MVC version 5.2, not 4.

Comment: The answer below should have been marked as the answer.  I needed this today and it worked as explained below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are using ASP.Net Identity. I assume you already have ApplicationUserManager. For example,

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
protected ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get { return _userManager ?? (_userManager = 
     HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()); }
}
```

Then you can call **FindById** method.

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
string username = user.UserName;
```

Comment: You can just pass username via either ViewBag or Model.